# Checkbox not staying checked in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, haml

I have this in part of my `form_tag`

```
%input{ :type => "checkbox", :name => "form", :value => "#{@t.form}"}
```

It saves to the database as `1` when i check it the first time, but then if i navigate back to the form it doesn't show up checked..

Comment: Are you using simple_form?

Comment: no, I'm using form_tag

Comment: Did you try my latest update?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this is not a recommended way to add the form and fields in rails. But, still to answer you question, you can go with this:

```
%input{ :type => "checkbox", :name => "form", :value => true, :checked => @t.form ? "checked" : ""}
```

Notice that I have changed the value part to `true` as it is the value attribute of the checkbox that will always have the same value.

Now there would be another problem, if the checkbox was previously checked and now you are unchecking it and saving the form then it will not save the value "0" of false in database.

> According to the HTML specification unchecked checkboxes submit no value. However it is often convenient for a checkbox to always submit a value.

Now to avoid this problem, you need to add a hidden field as well.

```
%input{ :type => "hidden", :name => "form", :value => false}
%input{ :type => "checkbox", :name => "form", :value => true, :checked => @t.form ? "checked" : ""}
```

Now, If the checkbox is unchecked only the hidden input is submitted and if it is checked then both are submitted but the value submitted by the checkbox takes precedence.

Note: I will recommend you to use rails methods for generating hidden fields and checkbox.

**Update(with form_tag helpers)**

```
= hidden_field_tag('form', '0')
= check_box_tag("form", '1', @t.form)
```

I think you are using HAML and the form is a boolean field in database.

Comment: this always saves to the database as `null`

Comment: Can you post the html output for both fields.

Comment: now it doesn't save anything to the database and the box is always checked

Comment: Don't know why but it was rendering the values to be "true" and "false" in rendered html. I have edited it again. Try now.